# Symfony - Avoid store related entities in preFlush Doctrine

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine-orm

I have an entity Subject:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Subject
{

    //... Some fields

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Subject", mappedBy="mark", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $subjects;


    private function calculateMarks()
    {
        //... Do something

        // return array with (abilities => marks);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function prePersist(){
        $now = new \DateTime();
        $this->setCreatedAt( $now );
        $this->setModifiedAt( $now );
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpdate(){
        $this->setModifiedAt( new \DateTime() );
        $this->setUpdated(true);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreFlush()
     */
    public function preFlush(){
        $marks = calculateMarks();

        foreach($marks as $ability => $score){
            $mark = new Mark();
            $mark->setSubject( $this );
            $this->addMark( $score );
            $mark->setAbility( $ability );
        }
    }
}
```

and the class Mark:

```
class Mark{

    // Many fields

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Subject", inversedBy="subjects")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subject_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $subject;
}
```

My problem is that I calculate and I create the Marks in the preFlush event (this is done this because in the official documentation is said this about preUpdate event: "Changes to associations of the updated entity are never allowed in this event, since Doctrine cannot guarantee to correctly handle referential integrity at this point of the flush operation"). When I save one subject, all work fine, but when I save many Subjects at the same time in a webservice, some marks are stored in the database many times.

The webservice action below:

```
public function setSubjects(Request $request)
{
    //... Do something

    $subjects         = $request["Subjects"];

    foreach($subjects as $s){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        //... Do something

        $em->persist($s);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return new JsonResponse($response);
}
```

Has anybody an idea of how could I avoid this behavior in the preFlush event?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always try to avoid `LifecycleCallbacks` unless it's simple and i'm only changing properties in the same entity.

to solve your issue i would create a function `calculateMarks()` inside the entity and tweak my loop to be something like

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
foreach($subjects as $s){
    //... Do something
    $s->calculateMarks();
    $em->persist($s);
}
$em->flush();
```

*NOTICE*

avoid `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` & `$em->flush();` inside the loop

Comment: Really $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); was not inside the loop, but I mistook when posted the question. However, $em->flush() yes, and this was the problem. The error was so clear, so easy, that was difficult to see, XD. I was looking in the wrong place. Thank you very much!